# npm soap with auth header

Tags: node.js, soap, npm

I am attempting to us the npm soap package to create a series of endpoints to a remote server that I can interface with through angular 4. I have read the documentation, but I am still unclear with regards to its usage. Below is the WSDL. How do I create a client that I can use to interface with the endpoint below? Here is the WSDL.

http://208.180.122.191:8081/niku/wsdl/Query/ts_pending_approvals?tenantId=clarity

My expectation is that I should get a response with the following:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://208.180.122.191:8081/niku/wsdl/Query/ts_pending_approvals?tenantId=clarity';
var args = {Username: "jdoe", Password: "*******"};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
client.Login(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

When i call console.log(client.describe()), I get the following:

```
{ ts_pending_approvalsQueryService:
  { ts_pending_approvalsQueryService:
   { Query: [Object],
     Login: [Object],
     WrappedLogin: [Object],
     Logout: [Object] } } }
```

However, when I call login and pass the username and password, i get undefined. using SoapUI, I was able to successfully complete the request, using the following. My question is how do I simulate this in node.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:quer="http://www.niku.com/xog/Query">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
    <quer:Login>
       <quer:Username>jdoe</quer:Username>
       <quer:Password>******</quer:Password>
    </quer:Login>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this on my own by setting the endpoint, which gave me the expected response token: 6312078__98C024DA-25CF-441E-A47B-A84DDE2FF140

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://208.180.122.191:8081/niku/wsdl/Query/ts_pending_approvals';
var args = {Username: "jdoe", Password: "*****"};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
   client.setEndpoint("http://208.180.122.191:8081/niku/xog")
   client.Login(args,(error,result)=>{
       if (error) throw error;
       console.log(result)
   })
});
```

It is also worth noting that when you're utilizing the package and you have send additional parameters, you may also have to send headers, which map to a namespace specified in the WSDL, in addition to complex structures that require multiple parameters. I was able to figure this out after some trial and error. See working example below:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1TS Open Timesheet

ppmRouter.get("/open_time_sheet",(req,res,next) => {

    var resourceid = req.query.param_resourceid

    var soap = require('soap');
    var url = config.wsdlQueryPath + 'open_time_sheet';
    var sheader = { Auth: {Username: config.xog_user, Password: config.password}}
    var args = { 
        Query:  {Code: "open_time_sheet"}, 
        Filter: {
            param_resourceid: resourceid
        }
    };

    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
        client.addSoapHeader(sheader,"","tns","Auth");
        client.setEndpoint(config.xog_url)
        client.Query(args,(error,result)=>{
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(result)
            res.send(result)
        })
    });

})
```